# Drawing picture by coordinates

Tags: java, netbeans

In the program I have a button with a picture and clicking on that button, it is necessary to draw that picture in the empty box below, with coordinates. How to do it in NetBeans?

Comment: This is too broad. Try to begin with something (even pseudocode or flowcharts) and come back here and ask once you have a more specific area to tackle (such as mapping coordinates to the screen, or changing a bitmap)

Comment: Show us what you have did on your side.

Comment: I'm making a game Mastermind and I have to do it with pictures, not colours, or numbers. Mine task is that clicking on the button, picture which is on that button draws on empty field below. I didn't done any code on that part od task yet.